# Create Extended partition taking entire HDD for data storage

Tags: partitioning, gparted, fdisk

Old forum posts suggests that hypothetically there's no reason you need a "Primary" partition and can make your whole disk an "Extended" partition (though it's always mentioned that `gparted` won't do it).

I have just got a brand new blank 8TB HDD to dump a heap of old stuff in. I will never use this as a boot disk, so fully "Extended" makes sense for me I think.

I've already tried:

1. `gparted`: I Only have the option of "Primary", others are greyed out.
2. `fdisk`: This was very confusing: It did *not* look like the simplicity presented [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/linux-unix-how-to-create-extended-partition-using-fdisk/), which is presumably from a simpler time.
3. `parted`: `mkpart` asks:

   > Partition name?  []?

   which seems to lead down a similar path as `fdisk`.

This seemed to be a question someone would have asked before, but today in 2019 the tools seem to have changed and I can't find the solution.

**How do I make only 1 partition *and an extended one only* on a disk using Ubuntu 18.10???**

Comment: Interesting question; thorough research...  **+1! ;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Cheers! I've always been vague on this stuff. Thanks again for helping explain it through.

Comment: No issue.  For other intelligent people that think out of the box like you, I've improved the readability of the question, removing your detailed investigations which still remain in the [revisions](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1152264/revisions) forever...  **;-)**

Comment: Do your really want only one large partition. And of course you have another large drive for backups? If file system repair is required then fsck may take forever. But if storing large files like videos, you may just want one larger partition. I prefer to have a small bootable Ubuntu install on every drive, even my larger flash drives and if only for emergency boot. Then you need a 100MB ESP & 20GB / (root) partition as minimums.

Comment: @oldfred Yes! But this is def multi-partition job for sanity -- this is my clouds storage mirror. I know it's old school but I want you know, 1x local version of all the cruft I've accumulated over the years. Though footprint is mainly personal photo/video media it's a mixed bag old tax returns/receipts, old coding project that sort of thing, few million files in all. Further I tend to carry 2x ubuntu USB boots at all times, I'm thinking if I have this disk but can't use those then all hope is already lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR:

You're using a `gpt` partition table which doesn't have the limitations the `msdos` partition table has: Just create a single large (Primary) partition if you need to and be done with it.

### The long version:

It's all about history and back in the stone age when I was a kid and dinosaurs still roamed the Earth, an `msdos` partition table could just have 4 partitions and that was it.  As the maximum size of a partition was 32 MB (yes: Megabyte) this posed no problems as HDDs only came in 10 and 20 MB versions.

Fast forward nearly half a century and lots of things were done to circumvent these limitations: larger individual partition sizes, extended partitions, ...

Today, however, *we don't need the `msdos` partition scheme any more* as we have `gpt` which has none of the limitations `msdos` has, so just create one single large primary partition as you can create up to [255 partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/306734/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-partitions-with-efi) with a maximum size of [9.4 ZB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#History)

So stop worrying: You're good creating a primary partition for the rest of the duration of your life!  **;-)**